# Prevent Delphi 10.2 from auto adding properties to TForm

Tags: delphi, dfm

I have a codebase that I'm working on that is written to work in both Delphi 5 and Delphi 10.2, until we get everything converted to D10.

Whenever I open a DFM file in 10.2 and save it, it automatically adds a `DesignSize` property to the `TForm`. This property doesn't exist in D5, so I get errors every time I open the same DFM in D5.

Is there any way to prevent D10 from auto-updating the DFM? Or is this not possible?

Comment: What about making the DFM read-only?
The DesignSize property is only written, when you have some child component set to Align = alNone and Anchors <> [akLeft, akTop]. Perhaps you can avoid this combination.

Comment: @Uwe Thats a pretty good idea. The only issue with that I can think of is having to make it writable when making changes to dfm, which isn't done so often.

Comment: @UweRaabe: That combination is difficult to avoid! I use it all the time to make dialog boxes behave well when resized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could clear them out using a utility when needed. The [JVCL](http://www.delphi-jedi.org/) includes a utility called DFM Cleaner that does this. In ends up in $(JVCL)\DevTools after JVCL is installed.

> **DFMCleaner** is a tool to remove unsupported properties from DFMs. If
>   you save a dfm file in one version of Delphi and want to use it in an
>   earlier version, chances are there are some unsupported properties in
>   it, generating an error when the form is opened in Delphi. What's even
>   worse, if the dfm is part of a design-time package, Delphi will
>   install the package without errors but when you try to access the form
>   at design-time (f ex if the form is used by a property editor), Delphi
>   generates an AV instead.